# Using an admin's credentials as an object don't provide access for Powershell Scripts

Tags: powershell, remote-access, credentials

I am trying to run a simple "hello world" print out on a remote server (a laptop sitting next to me) using Powershell.  I have it running when using `Invoke-Command`, but I have to leave `-Credential` set as `"UsernameHere"` and enter a password by hand.  In trying to make this script more advanced, I want to allow variable passwords/usernames to be passed in, so I started trying to create a `PSCredential` object to pass in (based on various posts here and other places around the net).

```
$Admin = "DOMAIN\username"
$PlainPassword = "plaintext"
$Credential = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($Admin,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PlainPassword -AsPlainText -Force))
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Laptop2 -ScriptBlock {Write-Output "Hello World"} -Credential $Credential -Authentication Negotiate
```

When I fill in the variables with the correct info, this fails.  However, if I use `-Credential "UsernameHere"` (instead of a `$Credential` object) and put the username in, typing in the password manually works and everything is happy... but the process is not automated.

I have checked all the stuff I could think of on the remote machine: the service is running, trusted hosts have been set to `*`, that specific user has admin privileges, etc.  Is there any reason why the set of credentials work when typing in the password when prompted versus having it be automated in a Powershell Script?

For Reference, the error message I get when running the script with "automated" credentials is:

```
[Laptop2] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message: Access is denied.  For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you leave off the `-Authentication Negotiate` parameter? Are you sure that your credential object has formed correctly? Can you do `$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Domain` and have it display your domain correctly? How about `.UserName` or `.Password` instead of `.Domain`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `-Authentication Negotiate` had no effect positive or negative.  Printing the password made me see what was wrong.  The real password has `$$` in it which made it break due to Powershell special chars.  If you word that in an answer I'll be sure to give you an Accepted Answer for helping (even if it is in a comment).  Thanks.